# Redirecting ASP to PHP

Tags: php, redirect, https

I am kind of hopeless or zero knowledge on PHP with some basic knowledge in PHP and need a bit of help to with .htaccees. I am doing two things at once. (1) changing Shared hosting providers from windows ASP to PHP (with hostpapa). (2) Change from http to https (finally). I have pages in the format of http://products.example.com/colpage.asp?col=bn30&pg=01 which I need to redirect to https://products.example.com/colpage.php?col=bn30&pg=01

my new site is simply all asp pages written in in PHP. Works identical to ASP. I need to preserve the same url.

Appreciate somone's help :)

Thanks
Nira

Comment: First question: Is it true that your hosting (a Windows Server running classic ASP) can also run PHP ? Second question: Is it true that your Windows Server is running IIS ? (if so, the redirection may be done on web.config and not .htaccess)

Comment: I am moving my providers. Originally I was with provider that had windows hosting. That is why I ran classic ASP. The new provider I need to redirect pages on is not on windows and I am using PHP. From what I have read the the only option for me is .htaccess just that I am not able to understand very well how to do the redirection. :)

Comment: Are you using Apache server?